Nuevas versiones de Python
Estoy empezando con Python y me instalé la versión 3.12 de la página oficial (www.python.org). He visto que Python no se actualiza sino que conforme salen nuevas versiones hay que instalarlas.
Mi pregunta se, si tengo instalado Python en por ejemplo c:\python\ python3.12, ¿qué es mejor? ¿Instalar las nuevas versiones en la forma c:\python\python3.12.2? ¿O desinstalar  la versión previa y hacer una instalación de cero?

Si es dentro del release, 3.10.x, 3.11.x, 3.12.x, etc se puede instalar encima de lo que ya hay instalado. De hecho, en el propio instalador aparece la opción de "Upgrade Now" cuando detecta una instalación anterior del mismo release. Pudiera dar problemas actualizar una instalación muy "sucia" con paquetes externos, en ese caso es altamente recomendable usar entornos virtuales.

Las versiones en python como en cualquier otro lenguaje de programacion te interesa siempre que sean versiones estables, sin vulneravilidades y que las utilize la mayor cantidad de personas posibles.
Entonces instalar siempre la ultima version quiza no sea siempre la mejor opcion. En el caso de que quieras cambiar a la ultima es practicamente igual borrar y luego instalar la nueva como actualizarla, para lo que si que te puede interesar borrarla e instalar la nueva es por si la version antigua la tienes sucia porque has instalado muchos paquetes externos, para evitar que esto te pase con todas

No es necesario tener la ultima version, cuando subas tu repositorio a una plataforma, generalmente las mismas soportan 1 o 2 versiones atrasados. Por ende, la versión estable de una versión anterior, es buena solución si se desea crear aplicaciones web por ejemplo.
